# Console Application with selectable text

Tags: c#, console-application

I want the user to be able to select the text (just like in Commandprompt) where you right click on the console application's surface and a menu will show, the user can then choose same functions as in commandprompt:

```
Mark
Copy        (Shortcut: Enter)
Paste
Select All
Scroll
Find
```

I have tried to Google after things like "C# Console Application select text" and other kind of things but can't seem to find a proper solution for this, since the user should be able to mark the text he/she wan't to copy or replace (with paste).

Do you have a solution for my question?

Comment: Does it really have to be a console app? It sounds like its the wrong choice for your needs..

Comment: Type Alt + Space in the Console Window. Then use cursor keys to navigate. Hey, you wanted a Console app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no managed methods to do this, but quick edit mode can be enabled through P/Invoke.  Quick edit mode allows console text to be selected with the mouse and copied, and for text to be pasted with the right-moue button. (See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317591) for a description of quick edit mode.)

```
// using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int mode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out int mode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);

const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
const int ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = 0x40 | 0x80;

public static void EnableQuickEditMode()
{
    int mode;
    IntPtr handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(handle, out mode);
    mode |= ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE;
    SetConsoleMode(handle, mode);
}
```

Comment: `0x40 | 0x80` == 192. `0x40`(64) + `0x80` (128) = 192. Why not set that variable to 192. What is the reason for using hex values with bitwise operator? Edit, accoring to Wikipedia `On simple low-cost processors, typically, bitwise operations are substantially faster than division, several times faster than multiplication, and sometimes significantly faster than addition.` I'm guessing the answer is because it's faster, but still why add when you can just set the number?

Comment: @Nick Enabling the quick edit mode [requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) two bit fields to be combined (0x40, `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` and 0x80, `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS`).  Performance-wise, since the value for the constant is computed at compile time, the line `mode |= ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` will effectively be compiled as `mode |= 192`.

Comment: This worked for me, and when I right-click on the console title bar the quickedit menu opens. However, if I right-click on the console black space, the console app exits immediately. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe I didn't get you but when you execute your console application it will be hosted into a command-prompt window which allows you to copy end past text where ever you like.

Comment: What type of console application?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do context menu in console apps or in the command prompt.

Console Apps act exactly like the default cmd.exe. You need to go to the menu by clicking the icon on the top left, and the edit menu will give you the options you've listed.

You can also go to properties to turn quick edit on.

Comment: You can get context menus in the standard cmd, but not when running a console app. But you're right in saying you can click the icon in the top left (or right click any of the chrome) to get the edit menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the command prompt app then you'll get the select/copy/paste behavior for free. If you want to implement a right click menu (context menu) I don't think you can.

Maybe to simple but you can implement a [simple switch based menu](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/Switchbasedconsolemenu.htm):